# FileEasy-Upload-Script path

Tags: php, path, ftp, upload

I need a good and easy php file upload system with admin panel to manage the uploads.

i found this: FileEasy-Upload-Script (https://github.com/asadhaider/FileEasy-Upload-Script)

It look very awesome, but there is one problem, and its the path. 
I need to have it on http://example.com/upload file but it keep sending me to domain.com ???

Any one can help?

Here is the link of my upload system uhttp://wewrap.dk/upload/

The guy who uploaded that system is not responsing :-(

(sorry my english)

Comment: By the way if there is any other upload system its okay you can send me the link

Comment: please add your codes

Comment: in the index.php there is only (check my answer blow)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imgup");
if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "images/$post_image");
    $query = "INSERT INTO img(post_image) ";
    $query .= "VALUES('{$post_image}')";
    $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
?> 
<form action="fileup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">       

        <label for="post_image">Post Image</label>
        <input type="file"  name="image">   
        <input type="submit" name="create_post" value="Publish">

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need one with administrator panel and users

Answer (score 0):

this is an awsome tutorial for file upload using ajax you must try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg

Comment: Thanks but i need one with administrator panel and users

Comment: sorry but i can't get. can you please explain a bit more what you want?